# How do I apply for a vanity callsign online?

Tags: united-states, fcc, callsign

[ARRL indicates](http://www.arrl.org/applying-for-a-vanity-call) that you can apply for vanity callsigns online by "by connecting to the [FCC's web site](http://wireless.fcc.gov/uls/)[ and clicking] on the icon entitled “Online Filing LOG IN”".

I can't seem to see any mention of vanity callsigns on the website indicated.

Is it possible to file vanity callsign applications online, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you logged in as indicated?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie: Yes, then I looked at everything on the following page and clicked on any links that looked promising, but couldn't find any mention of vanity callsigns.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie: Right! Found it eventually. Will post answer momentarily.

Answer (score 6):

1. [Go to the FCC login page.](https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsEntry/licManager/login.jsp)
2. Enter FRN and password and click submit.
3. Click "My Licenses" on the left.
4. Click on your callsign in the list of licenses.
5. Click "Request Vanity Call Sign" on the right.

Note: Steps 3 to 5 may not work unless you already have a callsign.

Comment: The "Request Vanity Call Sign" option is missing now from the online system :( Also, do not use other online systems like W5YI. They ask for your FCC password, and they don't even have SSL/HTTPS enable on their site. No thanks!

Comment: @ConnorRoberts, now it looks like you need to click "My Licenses," then click on your callsign, and *then* "Request Vanity Callsign" is available on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Optionally there are other ways to apply for a vanity call. You could use one of the licensing services like W5YI, ARRL etc. for a fee though I would not recommend that.

Obtain a copy of the FCC 605 form from any VEC or even grab it online, fill it in and snail mail it. There no longer is a fee to obtain a vanity call.

Word of note: Might want to verify the call you are looking to grab is available. Check QRZ.com first (although not always 100% accurate as they can be a few days behind the updating from the FCC) to see if it is available. 1x2 and 2x1 calls are near impossible to get due to the long waiting list (only available to Extra Class license holders). 1x1 calls are strictly for Special Event stations with short term authorization.

I would strongly recommend you have at least 2-3 vanity calls you would consider in case the most preferred one is not available and place them on the 605 form in the order of preference. If you only place one call request on the form and it is not available or gets assigned prior to your application, then no new call will be issued.